# Best way for maping html elements from material ui and rendering by map

Tags: html, reactjs

```
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Switch
                        onChange={(e) => changeSwitchState(e.target.name, e.target.checked)}
                        color='primary'
                        name='a'
                    />
                }
                label="A"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Switch
                        onChange={(e) => changeSwitchState(e.target.name, e.target.checked)}
                        color='primary'
                        name='b'
                    />
                }
                label="B"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Switch
                        onChange={(e) => changeSwitchState(e.target.name, e.target.checked)}
                        color='primary'
                        name='c'
                    />
                } label="C" />
            <span>D</span>
            <InputText
                className={inputValidation(inputValues.e, inputValues.f, inputValues.d) ? 'err' : 'validated'}
                id='d'
                keyfilter="num"
                value={inputValues.d}
                onChange={e => changeInputValue(e.target.id, e.target.value)}
            />
            <span>E</span>
            <InputText
                className={inputValidation(inputValues.f, inputValues.d, inputValues.e) ? 'errE' : 'validateE'}
                id='e'
                value={inputValues.e}
                onChange={e => changeInputValue(e.target.id, e.target.value)}
                mode="decimal"
                useGrouping={false}
            />
    )
};
```

here is mine code i want make code shorter and render this inputs and switch buttons by map way can someone explain how to do this and what is best practice and how to noth lost data which one im reciving by props way  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way would to be to setup configuration arrays for this. Ideally you would want to keep your inputs in the "Controlled State" in React so your user interface always represents your state.

Lets first configure a constant which holds the initial configuration of your formControlLabels, which holds information I can read from your code which you supplied.

It might look something like this, and can be defined outside of the component which uses it. Arrays holding objects for each input is ideal, since later we want to use `map` to render these in your return method.

```
const formControlLabelConfig = [
  {
    color: "primary",
    name: "a",
    label: "A",
    state: false
  },
  {
    color: "primary",
    name: "b",
    label: "B",
    state: false
  },
  {
    color: "primary",
    name: "c",
    label: "C",
    state: false
  }
];
```

similiarly for your textInput components

```
const textInputConfig = [
  {
    keyFilter: "num",
    id: "d",
    mode: undefined,
    className: "err",
    errorClassName: "validated",
    useGrouping: undefined,
    value: ""
  },
  {
    keyFilter: "num",
    id: "e",
    mode: "decimal",
    className: "errE",
    errorClassName: "validateE",
    useGrouping: false,
    value: ""
  }
];
```

We can setup a state variable using this initial configuration. This would be within the functional component you are using to render the `FormControlLabel` and `InputText components`

```
const [formControlLabelState, setFormControlLabelState] = useState(formControlLabelConfig);
const [textInputConfig, setTextInputConfig] = useState(textInputConfig);
```

we can then use map to render each component according to its config. I have mocked up something of what you will end up with

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const formControlLabelConfig = [
  {
    color: "primary",
    name: "a",
    label: "A",
    state: false
  },
  {
    color: "primary",
    name: "b",
    label: "B",
    state: false
  },
  {
    color: "primary",
    name: "c",
    label: "C",
    state: false
  }
];

const textInputConfig = [
  {
    keyFilter: "num",
    id: "d",
    mode: undefined,
    className: "err",
    errorClassName: "validated",
    useGrouping: undefined,
    value: ""
  },
  {
    keyFilter: "num",
    id: "e",
    mode: "decimal",
    className: "errE",
    errorClassName: "validateE",
    useGrouping: false,
    value: ""
  }
];

const SomeComponentName = () => {
  
  const [formControlLabelState, setFormControlLabelState] = useState(
    formControlLabelConfig
  );
  const [textInputState, setTextInputState] = useState(textInputConfig);

  const getInputClassName = () => {
    let className = "";
    //return the className on validation
    return className;
  };

  const changeInputValue = (id, value) => {
    setTextInputState((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      const index = newState.findIndex((config) => config.id === id);
      newState[index].value = value;
      return newState;
    });
  };

  const changeSwitchState = (name, chackedState) => {
    setFormControlLabelState((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      const index = newState.findIndex((config) => config.name === name);
      newState[index].state = chackedState;
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {formControlLabelState.map((config) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={config.id}
          control={
            <Switch
              onChange={(e) =>
                changeSwitchState(e.target.name, e.target.checked)
              }
              color={config.color}
              name={config.name}
              value={config.checked} //would need to check this. Not sure what attribute is used to set the checked state
            />
          }
          label="B"
        />
      ))}
      <span>D</span>
      {textInputState.map((config) => (
        <InputText
          key={config.id}
          className={() => getInputClassName(config.id)}
          id={config.id}
          value={config.value}
          onChange={(e) => changeInputValue(e.target.id, e.target.value)}
          mode={config.mode}
          useGrouping={config.useGrouping}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```